# collective.sendaspdf "Running wkhtmltopdf failed"

Tags: plone, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on installing collective.sendaspdf on a Plone 4.2.4 server.

This add-on provides two extra document action buttons, one "Send as PDF" and the other "View as PDF"

After following instructions on the [packages pypi page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sendaspdf). I get the following traceback when trying to click one of the aformentioned document action links:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute 
'_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/home/dan/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7
/threading.pyc'> ignored

2013-02-13 14:04:50 ERROR collective.sendaspdf Running wkhtmltopdf failed. Please check that you 
use a version compatible with your OS and the version is 0.9.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute 
'_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/home/dan/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7
/threading.pyc'> ignored

2013-02-13 14:05:55 ERROR collective.sendaspdf Running wkhtmltopdf failed. Please check that you 
use a version compatible with your OS and the version is 0.9.
```

I have tried pinning wkhtmltopdf to the version it requires, under the `[versions]` heading but that has done nothing for me. I have tried just loading the `collective.sendaspdf` alone under the `eggs` section but again, that doesn't work either. I have tried manually downloading them, putting them into my `src` folder and configuring the `develop` section accordingly, but that again gives me the same error. I've even tried easy_install but I get the same problems.

The instructions on [the pypi page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sendaspdf) can't be followed to the letter as I believe the url under the `[wkhtmltopdf]` heading leads to a corrupted archive (i can't use tar, gzip or bunzip2 to extract the files) however  he does have zip files contaning the source I have tried manually downloading and using easy_install) but to no avail.

I've been researching the

```
ERROR collective.sendaspdf Running wkhtmltopdf failed. Please check that you 
use a version compatible with your OS and the version is 0.9.
```

Error message that I'm getting but I don't seem to see any Plone users having difficulty, it seems most people are using this with Rails.

Does anyone know how I can:

1. Get this to work
2. Find an alternative way of converting HTML from Plone to a PDF.

I have tried Form2PDF, zopyx.smartpringng, and now collective.sendaspdf (this one I have gotten the furthest with) - except it is falling at the last hurdle

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear you've failed at the first hurdle: installing wkhtmltopdf. Either visit https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ and follow their instructions for installation, or look there to find the URL for a version compatible with your system